# How to receive firebase push notification in react native IOS?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way on how to receive push notification payload in IOS? In android it works by doing it this way:

```
firebase.messaging().onMessage((message: RemoteMessage) => {
   // Process your message as required
});
```

however it does not work in ios. It tried:

```
firebase.notifications().displayNotification((notification) => {
    console.log(notification);
});
```

or

```
firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
    console.log(notification);
});
```

still nothing works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I sorted it out by call it this way:

```
firebase.notifications().onNotificationDisplayed((notification: Notification) => {
    console.log(notification);
});

firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification: Notification) => {
    console.log(notification);
});
```